# c# wpf listview checkbox item

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, checkbox

I realize Listview for the photo preview.

```
<xctk:MaterialListBox InkEffectBrush="CornflowerBlue"  IsInkEffectActive="True" Background="Transparent" x:Name="TvBox" ScrollBar.Scroll="TvBox_Scroll" ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="TvBox_ScrollChanged" GiveFeedback="TvBox_GiveFeedback"  AllowDrop="False" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="TvBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" PreviewMouseMove="TvBox_PreviewMouseMove" Margin="0,0,0,10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <xctk:MaterialListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type xctk:MaterialListBoxItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="100" />
                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
                </Style>
            </xctk:MaterialListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <xctk:MaterialListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Columns="4" Background="#00FFFFFF"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </xctk:MaterialListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <xctk:MaterialListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
                        <Image Height="100" Width="200" Source="{Binding ImageData}"  Stretch="Uniform" />
                        <xctk:MaterialCheckBox Background="BlueViolet" Content="Выбрать" Click="MaterialButton_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="35" Margin="0,20" Width="130"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </xctk:MaterialListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </xctk:MaterialListBox>
```

[image: Screnshoot Listview.]
I need a checkbox on top of the image. [image: Example as needed]
Prompt please solve this problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this involve `MaterialDesign`

Comment: @satish-pai i use Xceed Toolkit Plus for WPF, but the implementation with the usual checkbox also suits. Thanks.

Comment: Check whether my answer suits your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `StackPanel` to combine to controls. `StackPanel` is meant to stack the controls inside it, so no matter even if you use `Zindex` , they wont overlap each other.

I used grid and then `Panel.ZIndex` , to make the control overlap, use margin to set checkbox accordingly over image.

```
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Image Panel.ZIndex="1"  Height="100" Width="200"  Source="Koala.jpg"  Stretch="Uniform" >
                    </Image>
                    <CheckBox Panel.ZIndex="2"  Background="BlueViolet" Content="Выбрать"   Margin="0,20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="35" Width="130">
                    </CheckBox>

                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Canvas Panel](https://www.wpftutorial.net/Canvas.html)

You should be able to put both Image and Checkbox into a canvas Panel and set their Top Left and ZIndex properties accordingly